# The type of column conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql, unpivot

I have two tables in separate databases that I'm trying to merge together to create a list of assets and their readings.  I came up with the following query:

```
use [db1]
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @colsUnpivot 
  = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
           FROM sys.columns c
           where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('db1.dbo.RUNTIME') and c.name != 'timestamp'
           for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')


use [db2]
set @query = '
SELECT
  a.[ID],
  a.[ASSETCLASS],
  a.[ASSETID],
  a.[READINGNAME],
  CONVERT(nvarchar(max), a.[SCADA_TAG]) as [SCADA_TAG],
  b.timestamp AS [READINGDATE],
  b.scada_value AS [READING]
/*,[PROCESSED]*/ FROM [scada].[PREPROCESSING] a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  [timestamp],
  CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [SCADA_TAG]) as [SCADA_TAG],
  [SCADA_VALUE]
FROM [db1].[dbo].[RUNTIME] UNPIVOT (SCADA_VALUE FOR SCADA_TAG IN ('+ @colsUnpivot +')) u) b
  ON a.scada_tag = b.scada_tag'

  exec sp_executesql @query;
```

However, the I am receiving the following error message when running the query:

[image]

When I look at the data type for the column mentioned, the db1 database has two different datatypes for the columns I'm trying to select-float and int.  The column that I'm trying to place these columns names from db1 into db2 is of the data type nvarchar(100). I've tried casting and converting the SCADA_TAG to no success. I just inherited this SQL integration from another dev and I'm rusty with pivot and unpivot functionality.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are unpivoting ALL rows in a column - must be same datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be late.  But what you could try first is almost do like a schema compare on the two tables.  To check if what columns or datatypes are not the same.  See script below.

```
SELECT c.name AS ColumnName,
    t.name AS DataType,
    c.max_length
FROM [DB1].sys.columns  c
INNER JOIN [DB1].sys.types  t 
    ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id ) = 'TableName'


 EXCEPT

SELECT c.name AS ColumnName,
    t.name AS DataType,
    c.max_length
FROM [DB2].sys.columns  c
INNER JOIN [DB2].sys.types t 
    ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'TableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, and this is probably not the most efficient way of handling this, is getting the columns from the source database and converting and selecting them into NVARCHAR(100) columns.

```
USE [db1]
DECLARE @tagNames AS nvarchar(max),
        @query AS nvarchar(max)
SELECT
  @tagNames
  = STUFF((SELECT
    ', CAST(' + QUOTENAME(C.name) + ' as nvarchar(100)) as ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
  FROM sys.columns c
  WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('db1.dbo.RUNTIME')
  AND c.name != 'timestamp'
  FOR xml PATH (''))
  , 1, 1, '')

USE [db2]
SET @query = 'select [timestamp], ' + @tagNames + ' into test_runtime from
  [db1].dbo.RUNTIME'
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

This gives me a table with the same structure and values as the original but all of the columns have been converted to NVARCHAR with the exception of the [timestamp] column.  I am then able to run the following SQL to return an unpivoted and merged result set of assets and readings:

```
DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS nvarchar(max),
        @query AS nvarchar(max)
SELECT
  @colsUnpivot
  = STUFF((SELECT
    ',' + QUOTENAME(C.name)
  FROM sys.columns c
  WHERE c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.test_RUNTIME')
  AND c.name != 'timestamp'
  FOR xml PATH (''))
  , 1, 1, '')

SET @query = '
SELECT
  a.[ID],
  a.[ASSETCLASS],
  a.[ASSETID],
  a.[READINGNAME],
  a.[SCADA_TAG],
  b.timestamp AS [READINGDATE],
  b.scada_value AS [READING]
FROM [scada].[PREPROCESSING] a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  [timestamp],
  [scada_tag],
  [SCADA_VALUE]
FROM [dbo].[test_RUNTIME] UNPIVOT (SCADA_VALUE FOR SCADA_TAG IN (' + @colsUnpivot + ')) u) b
  ON a.scada_tag = b.scada_tag'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
GO
```

If there is a more efficient method I am all ears.